# Gentoo Prefix project: where is bootstrap-bash.sh?

Tags: gentoo

How do I install [Gentoo Prefix](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Prefix)? I see a reference to `bootstrap-bash.sh` but cannot find it anywhere. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Where's the `bootstrap-bash.sh` script?

From the [Project Prefix](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Prefix) page:

> Note that, for systems where `bash` is missing, you need to bootstrap it first with the `bootstrap-bash.sh` script. **It can be found next to `bootstrap-prefix.sh`** as indicated by the guides.

Checking the [bootstrap guide](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Prefix/Bootstrap):

> The `bootstrap-prefix.sh` requires a working version of the GNU Bourne Again SHell (`bash`). If you don't have bash available on your system, you will have to bootstrap a `bash` binary first. Systems that often lack bash are the *BSD systems such as FreeBSD. If you don't have `bash` installed, download the `bootstrap-bash.sh` script from [1].

The link on the page refers (at time of writing) to:

http://rsync.prefix.bitzolder.nl/scripts/bootstrap-bash.sh

However, it is worth reading the [bootstrap guide](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Prefix/Bootstrap) thoroughly in entirety (and perhaps also the [technical documentation](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Project:Prefix/Technical_Documentation) as well as pre-emptively joining [`#gentoo-prefix`](http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=gentoo-prefix) on `irc.gentoo.org`) before going ahead.